# ExecutorService vs Asynchronous annotation

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb-3.0, executorservice

I have a list of `EJB`s, each one may run for more than 1 minute. I would like to run them in loop asynchronously, and then after a timeout of 10 seconds check for results using `Future` output.

As I understand, both `ExecutorService` and `@Asynchronous` annotation on method can give me this functionality.

When should I use `Asynchronous` annotations, and when it's better to use `ExecutorService`?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my point I'd stick to the EJB features and as a consequence I would use the @Asynchronous annotation which seems to be very well suited for your needs... ExecutorService is made for the Java SE world and I won't suggest you to use it directly inside a Java EE 6 server.

Comment: so u mean @asynchronous is better than create executor service? I use this on wildfly and my bos insist to use executor service

Comment: Opinionated: what's the motivation for not using `ManagedExecutorService`?

Answer (score 0):

Who is calling the EJBs?  If it's a servlet, then you might consider asynchronous servlet support.

Asynchronous EJBs are more useful than creating your own threads (via a ThreadPoolExecutor) because the container will establish thread contexts on the asynchronous thread: context class loader, java: namespaces, security, etc.  Your application server might also have additional qualities of service (e.g., monitoring, timeouts, etc.) for threads that it manages.